# mobile app open and view website does it count as consecutive days

Tags: bug, badges, mobile-web, stack-exchange, consecutive-days

I am using the website http://stackoverflow.com , but two days ago I have installed the SO mobile app. So I am viewing website content from the mobile app. My question is:

If I view from mobile every day,

1. does it count as consecutive days for the website?
2. does it help me to earn the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get credit for a visit to the site and get credit for the consecutive days activity you need to do more then just open the app and browse a couple of question. I use the mobile app throughout the day on other sites, and I take actions on the site such as voting on questions, flagging and other moderation related activities that you can do via the app and it will count for activity and consecutive days.